# global webform submissions admin page per user

Tags: webforms

I have a site where users fill diferent webforms and they can visit formX/submissions to view/edit their own submissions for every particular webform.
Now I need to give users something like a submissions administration page, where they can have a global view of their submissions to all webforms and be able to edit which one they choose.
is it possible to build this global submissions page with webform?

Answer (score 2):

You literally read my mind because I just added this feature to latest dev release of the Webform module for Drupal 8

@see [Users can view all their submissions across all webform instances.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2989964)